# Apps rearrange themselves after iPhone restart

Tags: applications, iphone

Occasionally, after i do a forced reboot on my iphone (holding power and home) all the apps rearrange themselves to alphabetical order and it removes all my folders. Is there a way to fix this?
I have a jailbroken iPhone 3gs 4.1.2

Comment: My iPhone 4s just did that. I restart my phone & "reboot" it both everyday and that never happened before til now. My phone is not jail broke either. What caused that to do that. I've had my phone for almost 2 yrs now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your phone is jailbroken, there's no telling what's installed on the phone, so getting help for the issue may be problematic.

That said, there is an option in Settings to reset your Home Screen, which is what you're seeing. My bet is there's a flag somewhere that does that when the phone is reset.

Comment: Yeah i see what your saying, theres no real way of knowing. Just putting it out there in case any one else has had this problem and found a solution. Its probably from one of the tweaks i got from cydia.

Comment: If you do find it, be sure to let us know. If it helps just one other person, it's worth it.

Comment: i just restored it.

Comment: Ok. It'll be interesting to see if it does it again.